# Transfer Domain from external ISP to GCP Cloud Domains

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

Is there a way to transfer any externally registered (e.g. GoDaddy, Namecheap) domains into GCP Cloud Domains (GCP > Network Services > Cloud Domains) ? In this case we would like to transfer a .CO.IN TLD but would be good to know in general if this is possible.

Comment: https://support.google.com/domains/answer/9003139?hl=en

Comment: @dishantmakwana "Google Domains" are accessible from within GCP? As in would be usable here: https://cloud.google.com/domains/docs/register-domain  ?

Answer (score 2):

Response from GCP support was to transfer the domain in via Google Domains, (a service external to GCP) but accessible to GCP (I guess you could say duh they're both "Google", but this could easily not have been the case in other companies).  This is because the Cloud DNS team do not have the capability to verify domain ownership within GCP.  Once the domain exists in Google Domains [via a support request] the GCP team can transfer it into GCP Cloud Domains and all the DNS configuration can be done from within GCP.